# .htaccess is not working in users' public_html directories

Tags: debian, apache-httpd, php

I followed a tutorial: http://www.techytalk.info/enable-userdir-apache-module-ubuntu-debian-based-linux-distributions/

but .htaccess is not overriding Apache's configuration. May be "AllowOverride All" in userdir.conf is not working for users' public_html directories.

Here is my userdir.conf of Apache:

```
<IfModule mod_userdir.c>
    UserDir public_html www/public_html
    UserDir disabled root

    <Directory /home/*/www/public_html>
    AllowOverride All
    Options MultiViews Indexes SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
    <Limit GET POST OPTIONS>
        # Apache <= 2.2:
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all

            # Apache >= 2.4:
            #Require all granted
    </Limit>
    <LimitExcept GET POST OPTIONS>
        # Apache <= 2.2:
            Order deny,allow
            Deny from all

        # Apache >= 2.4:
        #Require all denied
    </LimitExcept>
    </Directory>
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Did you try it first exactly as the guide shows, i.e. without the extra `www/` layer? Do the users' files actually get served?

Comment: Following text copied from http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/public_html.html
Multiple directories or directory paths can also be set.

`UserDir public_html /var/html`

For the URL http://example.com/~rbowen/file.html, Apache will search for ~rbowen. If it isn't found, Apache will search for rbowen in /var/html. If found, the above URL will then be translated to the file path /var/html/rbowen/file.html

Comment: If you found the answer to your own Question, feel free to add it as an Answer!